# c# Decimal to string for currency

Tags: c#, decimal, currency, tostring

To display a currency we do:

```
ToString("0.##")
```

For value `5.00` the output is:

```
5
```

For value `5.98` the output is:

```
5.98
```

For value `5.90` the output is:

```
5.9
```

I need the third case to come out with 2 decimal points, eg:

```
5.90
```

How can I do this without it affecting the other results?

Comment: Any reason you can't use the currency format string?  `value.ToString("c")`?

Comment: Why not simply do `someDecimal.ToString("c", new CultureInfo("en-US"))`? It then also applies the currency symbol.

Comment: @Tejs we're writing our own store and it supports multiple currencies, that wont fit in with the design very well unfortunately at this stage!

Comment: I don't think you can do that with any built-in or custom format strings (selectively either doing no decimal point or two decimal points).  You may have to add logic to select one or the other or implement your own `IFormatProvider`.

Comment: @Jacob that's what I was thinking as well, just going to be a PITA to do at this stage!

Comment: @TomGullen - Supporting multiple currencies isn't a problem, that's what the `new CultureInfo("en-US")` does. Try it with `new CultureInfo("en-GB")` or `new CultureInfo("fr-FR")`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I know this doesn't give you a format that fixes the problem, but it's a simple solution to work around it.

```
(5.00).ToString("0.00").Replace(".00","");  // returns 5
(5.90).ToString("0.00").Replace(".00", ""); // returns 5.90
(5.99).ToString("0.00").Replace(".00", ""); // returns 5.99
```

Comment: shouldn't you be using `5.00m` and the like?

Comment: (5.00).ToString("C");

Comment: How is this the accepted answer when the correct answer was given 11 minutes earlier?

Comment: @MikeDevenney Because the answer you're referring to didn't actually answer the question until August 2018.

Comment: @TravisSunderland Good call, I didn't notice that last part was added during the Aug edit.

Answer (score 26):

Try:

```
value.ToString("#,##0.00")
```

Or just:

```
value.ToString("C")
```

I know of no built-in way to expand out all two decimal places only when both are not zero. Would probably just use an `if` statement for that.

```
if (s.EndsWith(".00"))
    s = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 3);
```

Comment: The OP says that he wants the decimal portion to be omitted if it's an integer value.

Answer (score 11):

You could use an extension method, something like this:

```
public static string ToCurrencyString(this decimal d)
{
    decimal t = Decimal.Truncate(d);
    return d.Equals(t) ? d.ToString("0.##") : d.ToString("#, ##0.00")
}
```

Answer (score 10):

`#` means if there is no number leave it empty 0 means put a 0 if there is no number

> ToString("0.00")

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I did not know that.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm missing something, but can't you just do this:

```
decimal moneyvalue = 1921.39m;
string html = String.Format("Order Total: {0:C}", moneyvalue);
Console.WriteLine(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `myDecimal.ToString("N")`,

With "N" parameter will transform decimal to string, and the number of decimals to show will be defined by your SO settings.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimaldigits(v=vs.110).aspx