# ASP.NET MVC data annotation for currency format

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have following POCO with Cost as float.

```
public class CostChart
{
    public string itemType { get; set; }
    public float? Cost{ get; set; }

}
```

I need to return Cost in currency format e.g.

> $U 4.882,50.

What data annotation should I use?

This is how I am displaying in my view.

```
<td>@Model.Cost</td>
```

Comment: It's way overdue, but please don't use ever `float`s for currency. They're not precise. Use a `decimal` instead.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Have you tried using `DataType.Currency`:

```cs
public class CostChart
{
    public string itemType { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public float? Cost{ get; set; }

}
```

Alternatively, you could use `DataFormatString` like this:

```cs
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}")]`
public float? Cost{ get; set; }
```

But I prefer to set the display format with `EditorFor`. Here's a great tutorial on [Extending Editor Templates for ASP.NET MVC](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/extending-editor-templates-for-asp.net-mvc/) tutorial.

That way, you write the display logic of your currencies in just ONE place, and you don't need to add that extract annotation every single time you want to display a currency amount.

**--Edit**

To make it work in EditorFor, you can also add `ApplyFormatInEditMode = true` to the end of the `DataFormatString` making the line as:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

Comment: I tried above but it is not changing my value to currency on my view, it is still showing value without currency format. I am using this line on my view td>@Model.Cost</td>

Comment: Try the editorfor template version in the tutorial. In that case, it should be @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Cost).

Comment: @HTML.EditorFor() just convert label into editable field with value showing 1233.44 and not in currency format. Am i missing some point here>

Comment: Sorry, it should have been @Html.DisplayFor( ), like in the tutorial.

Comment: decimal is a better datatype

Comment: thanks @niico, I agree. I'd definitely go with decimal data type for this.

Comment: I have a similar issue, not with displaying the number, although DataType(DataType.Currency) does nothing for me (MVC 5 Framework 4.62) I can display the number using string formatting. The issue is that when posting back, the validation says that this is not a number, and the value is either 0 or null on the controller. I have seen the use of binders and JavaScript code, but seeing this as a common use, I can't believe we have to go to such lengths to have a monetary value posted back correctly.

Answer (score 11):

Try using:

```
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}")]
```

Visit this post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19800496/3642086

Answer (score 7):

try this :

```
public class CostChart
  {
    public string itemType { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public float? Cost{ get; set; }
  }
```

if you still do not see $ symbol, in web.config under  
write this line of code

```
<globalization culture ="en-us"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

All right, when we talking about data annotations, there's two things to take in account:

The Data Annotation, which is:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}")]
public decimal? Cost{ get; set; }
```

And the tag in Razor pages, which is:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Cost)
```

If you don't use "DisplayFor", data annotations is useless.

Another detail, if you want the decimal place, you should remove the last "0" after "C", as follow:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}")]
```

Hope it helps you and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can do in RazorView

```
@string.Format("{0:0,0.00,00}", Model.Cost)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this if you want to show 4 digit decimal points (the number after C is showing the point number)

- This works for float/decimal and double types:

  [Display(Name="Price")]
  [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C4}")]
  public double Price { get; set; }