# ASP.NET MVC USD Currency Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, currency

In my ViewModel, I have the following `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` on a property that contains USD currency:

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C2}")]
[Range(0.01, 100000, ErrorMessage = "Payment amount is required between .01 and $100,000.")]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[DisplayName("Payment Amount")]
public Double PrinAmount { get; set; } = 0.00;
```

When I enter a value of `$10.005`, I get the following validation model error from the `ModelState.IsValid` check:

> The value '$10.005' is not valid for Payment Amount.

When I enter a value `10.005`, the `ModelState.IsValid` is equal to `true`.

What do I need to do to modified the validation to capture both formats as invalid?

Comment: This has already been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975128/asp-net-mvc-data-annotation-for-currency-format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET MVC data annotation for currency format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975128/asp-net-mvc-data-annotation-for-currency-format)

Comment: @Kyle - Do you think my issue is because the property is a data type of `double` instead of a `decimal`?

Comment: Correct, you should not use double for money, but rather decimal.

Comment: @Kyle - For the short term, I am going to use the solution provided by ilkerkaran because going down the route of changing the data type will cause a lot more work than just using the regular expression data annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Regular Expression;

```cs
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+\.\d{0,2}$")]
```

the DataAnnotations above ensures 2 digits.

Comment: This regular expression fails when I enter `10.00` but works with `10.01`.  I need to allow `.00` in the usd currency amount