# How to make a textBox accepts Double value?

Tags: c#

As shown in the code,  I have to convert the double value to string in order for the textbox to accept it. Now b = 0.60 but when I run the program the textbox only shows it as 0.6 not 0.60.

How can I make the textbox show the double value as it is? I mean to show the 2 numbers after the DOT.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double b = 0.60;
    textBox1.Text = b.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`double` has an [override of `ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which can take a [format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), in your case you want `0.00` to force 2 decimal places:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double b = 0.60;
    textBox1.Text = b.ToString("0.00");
}
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/VLA46480

Comment: Just for other people's consideration, if you need a non-hardcoded string, you could perhaps [try something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3726337/1189566) to figure out how many digits are to the left / right of the `.` and then use a loop to build your format string for you. Then pass that to `Double.ToString(string s)`. Another solution to get that count is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483886/how-can-i-get-a-count-of-the-total-number-of-digits-in-a-number) but they both seem to have some limitations.

Answer (score 1):

You want to add formating as such:

```
double b = 0.60;
textBox1.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}",b);
```

`"{0:0.00}"` indicates that it will show two numbers after a float point and following part `0:0` indicates that there can be as much numbers as there is before the floating point. It will round to bigger side.

Also with c# 6.0 you can use `$`:

```
textBox1.Text = $"{b.ToString("0.00")}";
```

**Note:** This method is not the best case solver at all. Just wanted to show you other ways of achieving same result and also to show the new feature of c# 6.0.

Comment: You might also want to explain what the `0` before the `:` means when using `String.Format()` as well. Looking at that, it's kind of confusing and not very explicit for a newer developer.

Comment: @sab669 Edited. Hopefully it is a bit more clear now.